# Grouping overlapping integer pairs into a smaller array

Tags: python, numpy

I have numbers in an Nx2 array, and I want to simplify it to the minimum and maximums of each overlapping group, as a smaller Nx2 array.

A group is a group here if a number on either side of a pairing is in another pairing, and this extends globally to all pairings. In all cases, final pairings will only include a group of directly adjacent numbers.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([
       [ 45,  47], #group 1
       [ 46,  47], #group 1
       [ 53,  54], #group 2
       [ 63,  66], #group 3
       [ 64,  66], #group 3
       [ 65,  66], #group 3
       [ 66,  67], #group 3
       [ 68,  70], #group 4
       [ 69,  70], #group 4
       [ 70,  71], #group 4
       [ 70,  72], #group 4
       [ 80,  81], #group 5
       [ 92,  93], #group 6
       [ 94,  95], #group 7
       [ 94,  96], #group 7
       [ 94,  97], #group 7
       [ 94,  98], #group 7
       [103, 104]]) #group 8
```

desired output:

```
array([
    [45, 47], #g1
    [53, 54], #g2
    [63, 67], #g3
    [68, 72], #g4
    [80, 81], #g5
    [92, 93], #g6
    [94, 98], #g7
    [103, 104]]) #g8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `pandas` you can group by overlapping intervals and aggregate new start and end values for every group.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['start','end'])
df.groupby((~df.end.shift().ge(df.start)).cumsum()).agg({'start':'min', 'end':'max'}).to_numpy()
```

Out:

```
array([[ 45,  47],
       [ 53,  54],
       [ 63,  67],
       [ 68,  72],
       [ 80,  81],
       [ 92,  93],
       [ 94,  98],
       [103, 104]])
```

Comment: Something tells me that this won't work for general data, e.g. when the groups are not continuous blocks.

Comment: @QuangHoang - This solution will break with other data, e.g. a larger interval followed by smaller intervals without overlaps inside the larger interval. I think this only works when the interval bounderies can both be sorted ascending at the same time.

Comment: Here's a short example that breaks it for clarity `x = [[92, 100], [93, 95], [96, 98], [103, 104]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the regions are sorted...

```
def merge_regions(regions):
    # Init the first region
    final_regions = []
    final_regions.append(regions[0])
    for i in range(1, len(regions)):
        region = regions[i]
        last_region = final_regions[-1]
        if region[0] <= last_region[1]:
            # Regions overlap, get the new end
            new_end = max(region[1], last_region[1])
            final_regions[-1] = [last_region[0], new_end]
        else:
            final_regions.append(region)
    return final_regions
```

input:

```
[
       [ 45,  47], #group 1
       [ 46,  47], #group 1
       [ 53,  54], #group 2
       [ 63,  66], #group 3
       [ 64,  66], #group 3
       [ 65,  66], #group 3
       [ 66,  67], #group 3
       [ 68,  70], #group 4
       [ 69,  70], #group 4
       [ 70,  71], #group 4
       [ 70,  72], #group 4
       [ 80,  81], #group 5
       [ 92,  93], #group 6
       [ 94,  95], #group 7
       [ 94,  96], #group 7
       [ 94,  97], #group 7
       [ 94,  98], #group 7
       [103, 104]]
```

output:

```
[[45, 47],
 [53, 54],
 [63, 67],
 [68, 72],
 [80, 81],
 [92, 93],
 [94, 98],
 [103, 104]]
```